# Language logic about singular and plural groups

Tags: singular-vs-plural, quantifiers

I try to help some people with basic English, and I'm not able to explain why "Everyone" takes a "s" with the simple present verb, and why "People" takes no "s".

I explained "Everyone" as a group, and group means a plural, but have a singular form. Example: a football team.

But with "people", my explanation get confusing. How to explain it, considering the students ask for a logic, if they are learning from a language with a very different logic.

In linguistics, how is it called?

PS: why there is no "indefinite pronouns" tags, nor "linguistics" tag?

Comment: Does this help: Sometimes, things can be [both](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00048.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've checked this kind of page before, it can mean both, but it doesn't help as "everything" has a plural meaning also. So explanation becomes confusing.

Comment: I think the confusion stems from your understanding of the word "everything"? Although "everything" means "all" and may have many constituents, it is not plural. Perhaps once you start thinking of "everything" as singular, things will be less confusing?

Answer (score 2):

"Everyone" is equivalent to "Every person". Although we are talking about multiple people, we are grammatically using a singular.

- Everyone (singular) **works** overtime today.
- Every person (singular) **works** overtime today.

"People", on the other hand, is the plural for "person". "Persons" *can be* correct in certain circumstances. But you'll want to use "people" in most cases.

- People (plural) **work** overtime today.

---

There are ways that you can say the same thing about a group of people, but you can grammatically use the singular if you want to:

- The Coca Cola employees (plural) **work** overtime today.
- The Coca Cola staff (singular) **works** overtime today.

Comment: -1 for '"Persons" is not correct English.' This is quite wrong. What *is* true is that "persons" is *usually* replaced by "people", but it is still valid to pluralize "person" to emphasize the separate individual natures being discussed. (This is common in legalese, but not unheard of elsewhere.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy I accept that correction, but do you think this is the main focus for an English Language Learners question? 9 times out of 10, learners will pluralize "person" to "persons" wrongly instead of in the fringe case you're talking about.

Comment: That's true. I just don't think answers should misinform, even by quietly omitting corner cases that are exceptions to the "rule" they're putting forth.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I agree, but you also need to consider that examples should be simple and easy to understand, rather than getting complicated because of fringe cases. More often than not, an ELL poster will still be trying to learn the general rule; it'd be wrong to pull focus to fringe exceptions that they could start using more widely than they should. Nonetheless, my statement about persons not being correct English was factually incorrect, you were right about that.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all English plural nouns end in *s* or *es* but there are about 20 or so nouns with irregular plurals (that aren't stolen from Latin) - and *people* is one of them.  So it's treated the same way as a noun with *s* or *es* on the end.

*Everyone* is really the two words "every one" run together.  So it's really *one* modified by *every*.  You would use singular verb forms if *one* was the subject, and continue to do so if *one* was modified by another word.

Similar thread of logic with *everything*, *everywhere* and *everybody* (though "every body" does mean something different than "everybody" and "every where"  doesn't work.)

Comment: No, it's not about the irregular plural, it's about the agreement with the verb. "Everyone take a "s" with the single present". I though it was clear it means the conjugation, but maybe I should edit my question?

Comment: I thought there was confusion because *people* doesn't end with *s* or *es*.  But my last two points address your question I think.